# Adding custom xml to CMS page's Layout Update XML fails to load the script

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

I am trying to add Java script to a specific CMS page to be loaded in the `<head>` area. The scripts fails to load.

`name.min-1.0.js` and `name.Mode.js` are placed in `{magentoroot}/js`.

The following is placed in a specific CMS page, under **Layout Update XML** area. I do flush the Magento cache after save also!

```
<reference name="head">
<action method="addJs"><script>name.min-1.0.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>name.mode.js</script></action>
</reference>
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?  Is this conflicting with another script? How can this be fixed?

Comment: Can u please give me screen shot of `Layout Update XML`?

Comment: Just added the screen shot to the questions.

Comment: Have you checked if the path is exactly right? If you are hosting on Linux Magento will not find the file if the real path is `myfolder/name.min-1.0.js` instead of `MyFolder/Name.min-1.0.js`.

Comment: Yes I have checked that.  It is not a case issue. It will not load up even when I have it directly under `MyDomain.com/js/Name.Mode.js` or `mydomain.com/js/name.mode.js`.  It does not show up in the `View Page Source`!  Should this be placed under `skin/frontend/theme/default/js/`?